# PHP Issue with $_GET

Tags: php, get

I'm having a really weird problem with  a `$_GET` var.

This is my code :

```
if(isset($_GET['offer'])) {
    $params = array();
    $params['wifi'] = "%wifi%";
    $params['publisher'] = "%pubid%";
    $params['framework'] = "%framework%";
    $params['date'] = "%cachebuster%";

    foreach($params as $key=>$param){

    $array[$_GET[$key]] = $_GET[$key];

    }

    print_r($array);
}
```

This is the URL i'm sending :
http://example.com/track/?offer=g58fFPK49fk4&click_id=%guid%&wifi=%wifi%&publisher=%pubid%&framework=%framework%&date=%cachebuster%

And this is the weird output I get :

```
Array ( [%wifi%] => %wifi% [%pubid%] => %pubid% [%framework%] => %framework% [Êchebuster%] => Êchebuster% )
```

Why does `%cachebuster%` turn into `Êchebuster%` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Percent signs in URLs escape special characters. The url seems to be interpreted as [ISO 8869-I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout), and in that character set, `ca` is the code for `Ê`.

You should change the url to properly escape `%` as `%25`:

http://example.com/track/?offer=g58fFPK49fk4&click_id=%25guid%25&wifi=%25wifi%25&publisher=%25pubid%25&framework=%25framework%25&date=%25cachebuster%25

Answer (score 4):

Because `%ca` is the url-encoded form of Ê (0xCA)

`%` should be encoded as `%25`.

It's interesting that `%wifi%` works... I would have expected it to return `400 Bad Request` for that...

Answer (score 0):

While dealing with "%" character, we should use php function

```
//should be used for encoding URL
urlencode()
//should be used for decoding URL
urldecode()
```

Checkout php documentation in below link:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php